# Directive not detected

Tags: angular

I work on projects that set up hundreds of grids.
So I built a grid that automatically manages the refresh based on search, sorting and paging actions to be as productive as possible.

It works very well.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-grid-problem

I would like it to also know when an item is removed from this list to trigger the refresh. So I added a directive on the delete button, but my grid does not detect it.

Look in app.component.html:

```
<button mat-stroked-button type = "button" [delete] = "delete (row)" message = "Do you want delete <b> {{row.lastname}} {{row.firstname}} </b> ({{row.id}})? "> Delete </button>
```

And in grid.component.ts, the following code is never executed:

```
configureDeleters () {
     this.deleters.changes.subscribe (
       (deleters: QueryList <GridDeleteDirective>) => {...});
}
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: You seem to have overcomplicated a simple functionality.

Comment: I give you the complete code to understand my context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok a friend has found the solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-grid

Correct the directive's detection in adding { descendants: true } in grid.component.ts like this :

```
@ContentChildren(GridDeleteDirective, { descendants: true }) deleters: QueryList<GridDeleteDirective>;
```

Correct tracking of subscriptions in grid.component.ts like this :

```
  configureDeleters() {
    this.deleters.changes.subscribe(
      (deleters: QueryList<GridDeleteDirective>) => {
        deleters.map(deleter => {
          deleter.deleted.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(id => {
            if (this.loadCallback != null) {
              _.remove(this.pager["results"], item => item["id"] == id);
              this.items = this.pager["results"];
            } else {
              this.items = _.remove(this.items, item => item["id"] == id);
              this.items = this.items;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    );
  }
```